# How do I handle job secrets with MLRun?

Tags: python, mlops

I have a job that requires secrets to connect to S3 and a relational database. I can use environment variables to pass the connection information, but I am looking for a more secure way to handle this. My current code does something like:

```
import mlrun
fn = mlrun.code_to_function("db-load",
 kind = "job",
 requirements = ['psycopg2-binary']
)

fn.set_env("DBUSER","user")
fn.set_env("DBPASS", "pass")
```

Can you suggest a more secure way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

MLRun uses the concept of Tasks to encapsulate runtime parameters. Tasks are used to specify execution context such as hyper-parameters. They can also be used to pass details about secrets that are going to be used in the runtime.

To pass secret parameters, use the Task’s with_secrets() function. For example, the following command passes secrets provided by a kubernetes secret to the execution context:

```
function = mlrun.code_to_function(
    name="secret_func",
    filename="my_code.py",
    handler="test_function",
    kind="job",
    image="mlrun/mlrun"
)
task = mlrun.new_task().with_secrets("kubernetes", ["AWS_KEY", "DB_PASSWORD"])
run = function.run(task, ...)
```

Within the code in my_code.py, the handler can access these secrets by using the get_secret() API:

```
def test_function(context, db_name):
    context.logger.info("running function")
    db_password = context.get_secret("DB_PASSWORD")
    # Rest of code can use db_password to perform processing.
    ...
```

To learn more about handling secrets in MLRun click [here](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/secrets.html?highlight=secrets)